# Facebook connect issue with SSL

Tags: php, facebook, openssl, facebook-php-sdk

Recently I enabled ssl encription on my website. I'm using the PHP SDK to connect with facebook. The problem is that when I navigate throught HTTPS and I try to get the current user with

```
$facebookUser = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

the response always is false... if I try the same with HTTP it works perfectly...

Is there some setting that I need to change? 
I'm sure that ssl encription is working.
Facebook api didn't throw any exception...

Thank you.

Comment: Invalid or no certificate authority found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the solution to your problem, but I'd bet the URL isn't quite right.

To help diagnose this, Try using an http debugging proxy, like Fiddler2. It allows you to construct and submit http(s) requests, and examine the responses. Also you can use it as a proxy to see what http(s) messages get generated and sent by your app, and what responses come back.

Comment: Thanks @Cheeso, I try to diagnose it with a debugging proxy.